# How to hide option value using form_dropdown in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some trouble hidding the option tag using form_dropdown
How to hide each j_status row == close, then the option tag could be hidden
here's my script

```
<?php
$dev='';
foreach($j as $r)
{
    if(($r->j_status)=='open')
        $dev='echo ""';
    else if(($r->j_status)=='close')
        $dev='echo hidden';
}
    echo form_dropdown("id_j",$list_jid,"default",$dev,"id='some_id'");
?>
```

Comment: why are you looping it and echoing form_dropdown outside of loop?

Comment: ugh well, i have changed that form_dropdown technique to simple select option html mode and the problem solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dev='';
foreach($j as $r)
{
    if(($r->j_status)=='open')
        $dev='echo ""';
    else if(($r->j_status)=='close')
        $dev='echo hidden';
echo form_dropdown("id_j",$list_jid,"default",$dev,"id='some_id'");//place here
}

?>
```

1. [Form Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)
2. [form Validation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)